# Laravel 5 routes file is rendering multiple views

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5

I'm new to laravel and I'm trying to build a CMS with Laravel to learn it on the go. Now i've got this problem with my routes.

When I visit http://my.app/admin both the views dashboard.index and pages.page are getting loaded. I was under the impression that laravel handles routes in the order they are set in the routes file and if a route gets found everything after that doesn't get executed.
What am i doing wrong here? I'm using Laravel 5.

**Routes file:**

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin'), function()
{
    Route::get('/', array(
        'as' => 'cms.dashboard',
        'uses' => 'DashboardController@index'
    ));
});

Route::get('/{slug}', array(
    'as' => 'pages.page',
    'uses' => 'PagesController@page'
));
```

**Controllers:**

```
class DashboardController extends Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        return view('dashboard.index');
    }
}

class PagesController extends Controller {
    public function page($slug)
    {
        return view('pages.page');
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your view files as well?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem and it had nothing to do with Laravel.. This was in a javascript file included in the dashboard.index view:

```
$.get("skin.html", function (data) {
    $('body').append(data);
});
```